# Prove there is no infinite sequence ${c_n}$ which exists $y(c_n)=0$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=L\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ such that $p(x),q(x)$ are continuous fucntions.

Suppose $y(x)\neq0$ is a solution.

Prove there is no infinite sequence ${c_n}$ which exists $y(c_n)=0$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=L\in \mathbb{R}$.

I don't know how to approach this problem and will be grateful for help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a solution of this ODE on an interval $I$ and let $(c_n)$ be a sequence in $I$ with limit $L \in I$ and $y(c_n)=0$ for all $n$. W.l.o.g. let $c_n \not= c_k$ $(n \not= k)$ and note that $y  \in C^2(I,\mathbb{R})$. As $y$ is continuous we get $y(L)=0$. Moreover, for each $n$ we find between $c_n$ and $c_{n+1}$ some $d_n$ with $y'(d_n)=0$ (according to Rolle's Theorem). We have $d_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence $y'(L)=0$. Thus $y$ solves the initial value problem
$$
y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0, \quad y(L)=0, ~ y'(L)=0.
$$
The unique solution of this IVP on $I$ is $y(x)=0$ $(x \in I)$.